# Getting wrong output while validating python syntax using pep8

Tags: python

I want to validate python syntax using pep8 module using flake8 API. In order to validate, string is created which contains code those are to be ignored and later will be converted into tuple while passing to function to validate syntax.

```
ignore_code = """
        'E101','E111','E112','E113','E114','E115',
        'E116','E121','E122','E123','E124','E125',
        """.replace("\n",' ')

if flake8.main.check_file(fileName,ignore=tuple(ignore_code),complexity=-1):
    return False
else:
    return True
```

ignore keyword of flake8.main.check_file function should be

```
('E101','E111','E112','E113','E114','E115','E116','E121','E122','E123','E124','E125',)
```

Instead it gets,

```
("'", 'E', '1', '0', '1', "'", ',', "'", 'E', '1', '1', '1', "'", ',', "'", 'E', '1', '1', '2', "'", ',', "'", 'E', '1', '1', '3', "'", ',', "'", 'E', '1', '1', '4', "'")
```

How to convert multi line string to tuple by ignoring '\n' and extra spaces?

Comment: Why don't you leave out the quotes then pass `ignore_code.split(',')`? Or not start with a string to begin with, and just **build the tuple you need literally?** This problem is really nothing at all to do with `flake8` or syntax validation.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that when you do `tuple(ignore_code)` that's what you're passing in.

```
>>> tuple(ignore_code)
(' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', "'", 'E', '1', '0', '1', "'", ',', "'", 'E', '1', '1', '1', "'", ',', "'", 'E', '1', '1', '2', "'", ',', "'", 'E', '1', '1', '3', "'", ',', "'", 'E', '1', '1', '4', "'", ',', "'", 'E', '1', '1', '5', "'", ',', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', "'", 'E', '1', '1', '6', "'", ',', "'", 'E', '1', '2', '1', "'", ',', "'", 'E', '1', '2', '2', "'", ',', "'", 'E', '1', '2', '3', "'", ',', "'", 'E', '1', '2', '4', "'", ',', "'", 'E', '1', '2', '5', "'", ',', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ')
```

You've basically already said what you need to do.

> ignore keyword of flake8.main.check_file function should be ('E101','E111','E112','E113','E114','E115','E116','E121','E122','E123','E124','E125',)

You should make `ignore_code` the iterable you want to pass, IE

```
ignore_code = ('E101','E111','E112','E113','E114','E115','E116','E121','E122','E123','E124','E125')
flake8.main.check_file(fileName, ignore=ignore_code, complexity=-1)
```

If you ***really*** want to get the desired result from that multi-line string, you'll need to format it. Doing `.replace("\n", " ")` won't cut it because there are more whitespace characters than just newline characters in there and you've got the inner items enclosed in quotes. Further, `tuple(some_iterable)`  makes a tuple of the items in an iterable. A string is an iterable of its characters, but you want an iterable whose items are strings like `'E101'` not characters.

I was able to get the tuple you're looking for by the following.

```
import ast
the_tuple = tuple([ast.literal_eval(item.strip()) for item in ignore_code.split(",") if item.strip()])
#the_tuple
#('E101', 'E111', 'E112', 'E113', 'E114', 'E115', 'E116', 'E121', 'E122', 'E123', 'E124', 'E125')
```

To elaborate on that code and how it formats that multiline string:

`ignore_code.split(",")` will split the string up into a list, whose items consist of the parts of that string delimited by (and not including) the `,` character.  IE `["\n    'E101'", "'E111'",#etc]`

That will get you so far, but there's still whitespace in those items. `item.strip()` will remove leading and trailing whitespace characters from a string, such as newlines, spaces, tabs, etc.

Now you're almost there, but the items look like this `"'E101'", "'E111'",` -- they're strings containing the literal `'` character. To interpret these how you want, you can do a literal evaluation of the string with `ast.literal_eval`, which will evaluate `"'E101'"` to the string `'E101'`

Lastly, there's an item that is an empty string (due to the trailing `,` in your string) which will need to be removed. So the conditional `if item.split()` is added to the expression.

We put this idea into a generator expression `[ast.literal_eval(item.strip()) for item in ignore_code.split(",") if item.strip()]` which, in english, might be said something like

> "Give me a list, whose items consist of `ast.literal_eval(item.strip())` where `item` is every item from the list `ignore_code.split(",")`, but only if the value of `item.strip()` is a non-empty string."